# Using finally without a catch

Tags: java, try-catch-finally, throwable

I have a test I want to execute.  No matter if it passes or throws an error I want to close a case it opened.  I have at the top of the class String theCase = null;
Then in executeText() I set it once the case is open.

So I did this :

```
try {
    executeTest(tContext);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw t;
} finally {
    if (theCase != null) {
      closeCase(user, theCase);
    }
}
```

I am wondering.  Do I need the catch (Throwable t)?  I still want the error to be thrown, but first I want it to close the case.  If I don't catch it and throw it, will finally not throw it?  Or will it not be caught and throw the exception and not execute the finally?  I am a bit unclear about finally.

Comment: Is this Java? The behavior of the `try-catch-finally` block differs across languages (C#, Java, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need the catch (Throwable t)?

No you don't.

In fact, it is harmful, because if you catch and throw `Throwable` like that, then for some versions of Java you will need to declare the enclosing method as `throws Throwable` ... and so on.  (That was address in Java 8, IIRC.)

Answer (score 1):

Finally will be executed irrespective of whether an exception was thrown or not,  or whether it was rethrown from a catch block.